# Typescript lodash Groupby nested array

Tags: typescript, group-by, lodash

Can some one help me on how to use lodash groupby to achieve the below input to my desired output? I have tried lodash groupby methods as discussed in other links but could not achieve the output I expected.
**Input:**

```
inputList: dataMaster[] = [
  {
    "isSelected": true,
    "GroupKey": "G1",
    "GroupName": "Group1",
    "Key": "Key1",
    "Name": "Key Name 1"
  },
  {
    "isSelected": true,
    "GroupKey": "G1",
    "GroupName": "Group1",
    "Key": "Key2",
    "Name": "Key Name 2"
  },
  {
    "isSelected": true,
    "GroupKey": "G2",
    "GroupName": "Group2",
    "Key": "Key1",
    "Name": "Key Name 1"
  },
  {
    "isSelected": true,
    "GroupKey": "G2",
    "GroupName": "Group2",
    "Key": "Key2",
    "Name": "Key Name 2"
  }
```

Output expected as below:

```
outputList: dataGroup[] = [
       {
          GroupKey:"G1",
          GroupName:"Group1",
          Group:[
             {
                Key:"Key1",
                Name:"Key Name 1"
             },
             {
                Key:"Key2",
                Name:"Key Name 2"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          GroupKey:"G2",
          GroupName:"Group2",
          Group:[
             {
                Key:"Key1",
                Name:"Key Name 1"
             },
             {
                Key:"Key2",
                Name:"Key Name 2"
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

Comment: Please explain me why this has been downvoted so that I can correct it if I am not following the StackOverflow Process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// Change as necessary for your module loading configuration
import _ = require("lodash");

let grouped1 = _.groupBy(inputList, (dm) => dm.GroupKey);
let outputList: dataGroup[] = Object.keys(grouped1).map((groupKey) => {
    let groupItems = grouped1[groupKey];
    return {
        GroupKey: groupKey,
        GroupName: groupItems[0].GroupName,
        Group: groupItems.map((dm) => _.pick(dm, "Key", "Name"))
    };
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions about how this works.

Comment: Thanks Matt. This is working as expected! You saved my day! I got it!